# how to create regular expression for this pattern /posts/:post_id?

Tags: javascript

I want to evaluate url path which should match /post/:post_id pattern.

e.g. /post/1 , /post/2 , /post/mypost etc should match.

What should be the reg expression for this ?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: `/\/post\/\d+$/` ? What is `:post_id`? Is that text, or a placeholder for a number? I assumed a number. Please explain what the input URL looks like? Does it contain the full URL or just the path?

Comment: Thanks Ian I think /\/post\/\w+$/ will work ...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what `:post_id` is in the URL, something like this could work if it were a number:

```
/^\/post\/\d+$/
```

It basically says the URL must end with `/post/[0-9]+`. If `:post_id` were any value, you could use:

```
/^\/post\/\w+$/
```

Which basically says the URL must end with `/post/[0-9A-Za-z_]+`. Any other characters you want to accept , you can add.

To check begin with sort of pattern  ^ is used.

Comment: thanx alot Ian :) , can u suggest any online resource to master reg-expressions ?

Comment: @Ashish The MDN website explains the different characters and uses pretty well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: added caret to ensure that xyz/post/1 will not match.

Comment: @Ashish Sounds good, wasn't sure if you wanted to allow anything before this text. The `$` was to ensure this text was at the end (and nothing came after it, like `/post/2/asdf`. So yeah, it was up to you to know/decide that there should be nothing before the `/post/` part, like `asdf/post/1`, and the `^` would definitely ensure that.